# MudBlazor: Run Task when clicking on backdrop

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

The backdrop click can be disabled with MudBlazor dialog. But how to run a Task when clicking on the backdrop?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `OnBackdropClick` EventCallback.

For this to work the `DisableBackdropClick` option should **Not** be true. However if you implement your own logic/Task when backdrop is clicked, this will override the default logic for backdrop click, which is to close/cancel the dialog.

```
<MudDialog OnBackdropClick="@HandleBackdropClick">
    <TitleContent>
        <p>Times backdrop clicked: @timesBackDropClicked</p>
    </TitleContent>
</MudDialog>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; }
    int timesBackDropClicked;
    void HandleBackdropClick(MouseEventArgs eArgs)
    {
        timesBackDropClicked++;
    }
}
```

[mudblazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEcHkpEfUWPdeLzp)